# Python Crash Course Alien Invasion file has no attribute 'blit'

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and just started reading "Python Crash Course" around a month back. While working on one of the projects, I encountered this error: `AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'blit'`

Code:

main:

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    '''overall class to manage game behavior'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''initialize pygame'''
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

        # bg color
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        '''main loop'''
        while True:
            # watch for keyboard and mouse events
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # draw screen
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()
            # make most recent screen visible
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # make an instance of game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

ship:

```
import pygame
class Ship:
    '''class to manage ship'''

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        '''initialize ship and start pos'''
        self.screen = ai_game
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        # load ship
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # start each new ship
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        '''draw a ship at current location'''
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

full error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\alien_shooter\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    ai.run_game()
  File "C:\Users\richh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\alien_shooter\main.py", line 32, in run_game
    self.ship.blitme()
  File "C:\Users\richh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\alien_shooter\ship.py", line 18, in blitme
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

Comment: What's the _full_ error message?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the _whole_ error message.

Comment: I would guess that the issue is in the Ship class, because that's where the `blit()` method is called.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I don't see `blit` anywhere in your code. Is it supposed to be `blitme`? Maybe the error is elsewhere, or maybe you're editing/running the wrong file. But also, why is there a space in the type name in the error message (`Alien Invasion`)? That's not possible. Did you manually edit the error message? Don't do that; provide the [verbatim error message, with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). And make sure to provide a [mre]. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are confused over whether you are sending the entier `AlienInvasion` instance to `Ship`, or just the pygame screen.  There are two ways to clear that up.  Instead of this:

```
import pygame
class Ship:
    '''class to manage ship'''

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        '''initialize ship and start pos'''
        self.screen = ai_game
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
```

just save the `screen` item:

```
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
```

A better way would be just to pass the pygame instance, instead of the whole AlienInvasion instance.  So, in AlienInvasion, change this:

```
        self.ship = Ship(self)
```

to this:

```
        self.ship = Ship(self.screen)
```

Then in Ship, change the last line of this:

```
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        '''initialize ship and start pos'''
        self.screen = ai_game
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
```

to this:

```
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.get_rect()
```

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of PCC. The `Ship` class uses the overall game instance to access two different things: the screen and the settings. So your idea would work, but it will later require passing the settings object as well. I wrote this code the way it's shown so there wouldn't be a growing number of arguments to keep up with as the game grows more complex.

Answer (score 0):

In the file ship.py, in the line:

```
self.screen = ai_game
```

It's supposed to be:

```
self.screen = ai_game.screen
```

Doing this would make the attribute screen in Ship to be equal to the attribute screen in your main. Only then you could pass in the values of screen in main to your blit function.